# Can we use "name" as a column name in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, ddl, create-table

Can we use "name" as a column name in PostgreSQL?

I have tried it out and the table gets created successfully. Will it get any errors when I will be performing any operation on table or table data?

Is name the reserved keyword?

UPDATE: Tried this

```
select * from pg_get_keywords()
```

and found that "name" is the unreserved. Still want to confirm if i can use that name?

Comment: I guess you have answered your own question.

Comment: `NAME` is not a reserved keyword according to the [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html).  But you still probably should not be using it if it appears on that list.

Answer (score 9):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html#DATATYPE-CHARACTER-SPECIAL-TABLE

> "name" is internal type for object names

So yes - you can:

```
t=# create table "b@dPract!c3" ("name" text, "date" timestamptz);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into "b@dPract!c3" values('wrong',now());
INSERT 0 1
t=# select * from "b@dPract!c3";
 name  |             date
-------+-------------------------------
 wrong | 2018-05-09 08:38:53.612212+01
(1 row)
```

**should you do it? Surely not!** naming columns with data type names is easy, but really bad practice

Comment: I'd go so far as to say any name that requires quoting is best avoided. It makes usage more difficult. +1